# Starting Terminal as full screen by default

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

In Mac OS X 10.8, how can I make terminal.app open in full screen by default?

It appears that it opens full screen if I control click the terminal app before quitting and then choose close. But I typically command + q to exit out of the application. How can I command + q the application, and the next time it opens have it be in full screen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another user posted this answer, but it appears they deleted it. You'll want to uncheck the "Close windows when quitting an application" option: [image: screenshot of dialog described]

Answer (score 2):

If you have disabled Resume, you could set Settings > Shell > Startup > Run command to `osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to keystroke "f" using {control down, command down}'`.

In iTerm you can make new windows open in full screen by selecting Preferences > Profiles > Window > Settings for New Windows > Style > Fullscreen. If you haven't disabled Resume, full screen windows are restored in full screen like in Terminal.

iTerm also has an option to use custom full screen windows that don't have animations for changing spaces, don't disable ⌘H, and allow placing other windows over them. There is a bug where the menu bar is always shown in restored custom full screen windows though. If you haven't disable Resume from System Preferences, you could also run `defaults write com.googlecode.iterm2 NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows -bool false`.