# On startup, how can I configure Terminal.app to open in fullscreen?

Tags: mac, osx-mountain-lion, terminal.app

When my mac reboots, I would like to have Terminal open in full-screen mode (not full window size). I'm on OS X 10.8.2. How can I configure this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have Terminal open in full screen when logging in:

1. Open Terminal, enter full screen (View>Enter Full Screen), then close it.
2. Open System Preferences>General and uncheck the "Close windows when quitting an application" option:

   [image]
3. Then add Terminal to your login items in System Preferences>Users & Groups:

   [image]

Next time you log in Terminal will open in full screen.

Comment: Doing this makes Terminal open in full window size not full screen mode

Comment: Do we mean the same thing with 'full screen'/'full window size'? **Full screen** is what you get with View>Enter Full Screen. **Full window size** is what you get when clicking the green button in the top-left corner of the application window. I tested my answer on a Mac running OS X 10.8.2 and worked.

Comment: Yes, we mean the same thing. The only thing missing from your explanation was found here: http://superuser.com/questions/543699/starting-terminal-as-full-screen-by-default

Comment: Added that to my answer, great you got it working.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to enable Resume, you could also set Settings > Shell > Startup > Run command to `osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to keystroke "f" using {control down, command down}'`.

In iTerm you could:

- Select Profiles > Window > Settings for New Windows > Style > Fullscreen
- Uncheck General > Use Lion-style full screen windows (unless you like the animations for changing spaces, having ⌘H disabled, and not being able to open other windows over full screen windows)
- Run `defaults write com.googlecode.iterm2 NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows -bool false` if you haven't disabled Resume in System Preferences (there is a bug where the menu bar is always shown in restored full screen windows)