# Automatic full screen mode macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, macos-sierra

I am new to macOS. My goal is to automatically open any application in full screen mode achieve the same result as by ctrl + cmd + f combination. I hope it is possible to set that in system preferences.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: If you close a window with the red dot, then the app will forget its last status. If you always remember that Cmd/Q is to quit an app, then windows will be remembered next launch, assuming you have the pref set that ljk mentions in his answer. [This also applies if you reboot the machine - apps & windows will be correctly restored if you didn't actually close them first]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can uncheck the "Close windows when quitting an application" option" under System Preference.

[Starting Terminal as full screen by default](https://superuser.com/questions/543699/starting-terminal-as-full-screen-by-default)

and

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4140495?tstart=0

Comment: ...which I always thought was the default setting anyway. I'm betting we have a red dot closer, not an app quitter ;)

Comment: when I close app via cmd + Q it works but not for every application. For Chrome it does not work. Do you know why?

Comment: Chrome pretty much ignores the standard Mac toolbox in all respects - I guess that one is just another example of "we do it our way & !%^!* you."

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using something like [BetterTouchTool](https://www.boastr.net/downloads/)? You can drag your windows to various corners and edges of the screen to make them full screen, half screen, quarter screen, etc. I personally use it because it's very customizable and it's easy to map shortcuts to common functions like full screen, left-half and right-halfscreen. Fwiw, it also offers the ability to customize the behavior your touchpad and mouse.

Comment: Does it allow the functionality asked for by the poster?

Comment: Not quite but I’m don’t think it’s possible to open an app in full screen mode automatically.